# Perfect Number Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am trying to find the perfect number. Needs to sum up the proper divisors and then evaluate the sum compared to the original number. I am just learning Scheme. It sometimes makes sense and then throws a loop it seems.

```
(define (N num sum)
    (if (= num 1)
      sum
    (if ( = ( modulo num sum ) 0)
      (N (- num 1)(* num sum)))))

  ;( + (sum (+ (N num sum) 1)))
  ;( - (N num sum) 1)))

(print "Enter a positive integer: ")
(define integer (read))

(define (perfect)
  (if (= num sum)
    (print "perfect"))
    (if (< num sum)
    (print "abundant")) 
    (print "deficient"))
```

Comment: Which Scheme system (programming environment) are you using?

Comment: Scheme is 'lexically scoped': identifiers need to be introduced (defined/'bound') before use. `perfect` could start `(define (perfect num) (if (= num (sum-divisors num)) ...` (with a preceding definition of `sum-divisors`)